# Get frontend user machine name or ip or something unique to user in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to make a audit table where every action on a particular table_A captured in other table_audit.

Unable to find any unique identifier which can be used to capture and decide so & so user had done this activity, something like this. Hope you get my requirement

Example: Employee/user whose companies laptop/machine name is 'JerryLap' apply for leave, i need to know capture 'JerryLap' and if he/she login and apply from different system with 'TomPC' then capture 'TomPC' and push it into database table with IP address.

Version: PostgreSQL 12.12 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

Comment: [current_user](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-info.html)

Comment: `inet_client_addr()`?

Comment: Show your Postgres version and define "user".